# Spring MVC increase counter based on Session Requests/IP Adresses

Tags: java, spring, validation, session, model-view-controller

I am starting an application that allows users to monetize their content. I'm basing the amount of earned money on the view count on a page, so the page needs a validated way to count views. As far as I know, the best way to have one user be able to increment the view counter only once (just like YouTube videos), is using `Session Requests` or `IP Adresses.`

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewPhoto/{id}")
    public String viewPhoto(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        Photo photo = photoService.getPhotoById(id);
        //irrelevant code
        Long commentNumber = commentService.getCommentNumber(id); //number of comments
        List<Comment> commentList = commentService.getComments(); //getting comments
        List<Reply> replyList = commentService.getRepliesByComment(); //getting replies for each comment
        model.addAttribute("replyList", replyList);
        model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList);
        model.addAttribute("photo", photo);
        model.addAttribute("commentNumber", commentNumber);
        //if the viewer is valid and hasn't viewed the photo, increment view count
        return "viewPhoto";
    }
```

If I retrieve the session object using `@SessionAttribute` how can I use it to validate if the view is unique or not?

Sorry if it's a noob question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can extract visitor's IP address using `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddress()`

Below is the sample code, haven't tested it but it should be fine.

```
@RequestMapping("/viewPhoto/{id}")
public String viewPhoto(@PathVariable int id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Photo photo = photoService.getPhotoById(id);
    //irrelevant code
    Long commentNumber = commentService.getCommentNumber(id); //number of comments
    List<Comment> commentList = commentService.getComments(); //getting comments
    List<Reply> replyList = commentService.getRepliesByComment(); //getting replies for each comment
    model.addAttribute("replyList", replyList);
    model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList);
    model.addAttribute("photo", photo);
    model.addAttribute("commentNumber", commentNumber);
    //if the viewer is valid and hasn't viewed the photo, increment view count

    String remoteIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
    //enter logic here to check if user with this IP has already viewed or not
    return "viewPhoto";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the question still remains, how can I check if the IP address has viewed the photo or not? :)

Comment: Well, you need to have  a database or cache in place, where you keep the mapping of image/page against the IP address. A bad & quick implementation can be like: `Map<Image, List<IPAddress>> map = ..; if(map.get(image).contains(IPAddress)) { //not first visit }`

Comment: This came to my mind at first, but I thought it wasn't a wise decision to make another table at the database to store the views. However, it seems that it's necessary. Since I'm storing the IP Address which can be stored as a String, do you think that I should make another Model for a view, or would it slow down the application too much? If I make another model with a link to the photo, the database has a limit on rows in a table, if a picture has 10 000 views, it'll become a problem to load al 10 000 models. Is there another way to implement it?